# What's purpose of facebook application key

Tags: facebook, key, oauth-2.0

When you register a facebook application you get

application id: 123455678
application key: hkjhkh3434hkklljk
application secret: jkjljlj1233455jk

For OAuth 2 only application id (a.k.a. client_id) and application secret (a.k.a. client_secret) are userful.

Wondering what's purpose of the application key? Is it for some backend purpose? If yes, then what's point of exposing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just thinking loud here.

I guess this is only present for backward compatibility, specifically for old [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/198) implementation and REST API where the `APP_KEY` was used.

As you can see in the [`FB.init`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init) Javascript-SDK:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

They don't mention the `apiKey` which is the code used with the ***NEW*** [PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php).
Now if you go to the old [connect-js example](https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/blob/master/examples/jquery/login.html):

```
FB.init({ apiKey: '48f06bc570aaf9ed454699ec4fe416df' });
```

So debugging the `connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` file (using [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)):

```
FB.provide('', {
    init: function (a) {
        a = FB.copy(a || {}, {
            logging: true,
            status: true
        });
        FB._apiKey = a.appId || a.apiKey;
        if (!a.logging && window.location.toString().indexOf('fb_debug=1') < 0) FB._logging = false;
        FB.XD.init(a.channelUrl);
        if (FB._apiKey) {
            FB.Cookie.setEnabled(a.cookie);
            a.session = a.session || FB.Cookie.load();
            FB.Auth.setSession(a.session, a.session ? 'connected' : 'unknown');
            if (a.status) FB.getLoginStatus();
        }
        if (a.xfbml) window.setTimeout(function () {
            if (FB.XFBML) FB.Dom.ready(FB.XFBML.parse);
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

You can see here that it's checking the presence of `apiId` or `apiKey` and then trying to call the graph api and *else* the rest api:

```
FB.provide('', {
    api: function () {
        if (typeof arguments[0] === 'string') {
            FB.ApiServer.graph.apply(FB.ApiServer, arguments);
        } else FB.ApiServer.rest.apply(FB.ApiServer, arguments);
    }
});
```

And:

```
graph: function () {
    var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        f = a.shift(),
        d = a.shift(),
        c, e, b;
    while (d) {
        var g = typeof d;
        if (g === 'string' && !c) {
            c = d.toLowerCase();
        } else if (g === 'function' && !b) {
            b = d;
        } else if (g === 'object' && !e) {
            e = d;
        } else {
            FB.log('Invalid argument passed to FB.api(): ' + d);
            return;
        }
        d = a.shift();
    }
    c = c || 'get';
    e = e || {};
    if (f[0] === '/') f = f.substr(1);
    if (FB.Array.indexOf(FB.ApiServer.METHODS, c) < 0) {
        FB.log('Invalid method passed to FB.api(): ' + c);
        return;
    }
    FB.ApiServer.oauthRequest('graph', f, c, e, b);
},
rest: function (e, a) {
    var c = e.method.toLowerCase().replace('.', '_');
    if (FB.Auth && c === 'auth_revokeauthorization') {
        var d = a;
        a = function (f) {
            if (f === true) FB.Auth.setSession(null, 'notConnected');
            d && d(f);
        };
    }
    e.format = 'json-strings';
    e.api_key = FB._apiKey;
    var b = FB.ApiServer._readOnlyCalls[c] ? 'api_read' : 'api';
    FB.ApiServer.oauthRequest(b, 'restserver.php', 'get', e, a);
},
```

As you can see here, it's used with the [Old Rest API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/), reading the documentation there:

> The REST API supports both OAuth 2.0
>   **as well as an older, custom
>   authorization signature scheme**. See
>   the authentication upgrade guide for
>   information about how to upgrade your
>   existing sessions to OAuth 2.0.

***So the `APP_KEY` is definitely there for backward compatibility!***

Comment: I think it makes sense, it's definitely for backward compatibility. I also noticed that for logout one still needs the application key, e.g., to logout one invokes `http://www.facebook.com/logout.php?api_key={application key}&;session_key={oauth 2.0 code}";` For _OAuth 2.0_ compatibility it should have been `http://www.facebook.com/logout.php?api_id={client_id}&;app_secret={client_secret}&;session_key={oauth 2.0 code};` or simply `http://www.facebook.com/logout.php?session_key={oauth 2.0 code};` It looks like facebook is inconsistent in terms of implementing OAuth 2.0.

Comment: @user613343: well, using their PHP-SDK...the logout URL generated from `$facebook->getLogoutUrl()` call looks like: `https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://domain.com/&access_token=XXXXXXXX`